# Camel route with Spring Batch: No JobLauncher

Tags: apache-camel, spring-batch

I'm deploying a Spring Batch job triggered by a Camel route. Here is the Spring Batch config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class JobConfig
{
    ...

    @Bean(name = "personJob")
    public Job personJob(JobCompletionNotificationListener personListener, Step personStep)
    {
        return jobBuilderFactory
          .get(...)
          .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
          .listener(...)
          .flow(...)
          .end()
          .build();
    }
    ...
```

The Camel route looks like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder
{
    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception
    {
      from("file://...")
      ...
      .to("spring-batch:personJob?jobLauncherRef=jobLauncher");
}
```

Running the route above raises the following exception:

```
[ERROR]     Caused by: org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint: spring-batch://personJob?jobLauncherRef=jobLauncher due to: No JobLauncher named jobLauncher found in the registry.
[ERROR]     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No JobLauncher named jobLauncher found in the registry."}}}}
```

However, the documentation clearly states:

> The @EnableBatchProcessing works similarly to the other @Enable*
> annotations in the Spring family. In this case, @EnableBatchProcessing
> provides a base configuration for building batch jobs. Within this
> base configuration, an instance of StepScope is created in addition to
> a number of beans made available to be autowired:
>
> ```
> JobRepository: bean name "jobRepository"
>
> JobLauncher: bean name "jobLauncher"
> ...
> ```

So, there should be a bean named "jobLauncher" of the type JobLauncher. Why isn't it found in the registry ?

Many thanks in advance,

Seymour

Comment: I'm not familiar with Camel but does it bootstrap into it's own spring beam factory context that is different from the one loading the spring batch job launcher sub system?

Comment: +1 to what Atmas said. How does Camel resolve references like `jobLauncherRef` defined in expressions like `from("file://...").to("spring-batch:personJob?jobLauncherRef=jobLauncher");`? Does it see bean references defined by the `JobConfig` spring configuration class?